# Static Variables in jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery, variables, static

I want to make my URL a static variable in one html file, and I want to access that URL from other html files.
Can anyone suggest to me how I can do it in jquery.

Comment: You define variable in some `abrakadabra.js` like `var url = 'http://stackoverflow.com';` and include this JS file into your html and you'll be able to use this variable, but using global variables is not he best idea. Why you need this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to ensure the JS file is included on all pages - e.g. in a template header file and then do the following:

Easy method:

```
var myDomain = document.location.hostname;
```

Function:

```
function getDomainName(url) {
    var domain = ((url||'')+'').match(/^http:\/\/[^/]+/);

    return domain ? domain[0] : null;
}
```

You would need to pass the URL in as a string like the following:

```
function getDomainName('http://www.domain.com') {}
```

This could help

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html